# Blank line before the return statement in a Python function

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pep8

I can't find any PEP reference to the use of a blank line before return so would like to know what is the common practice.

Example A1:

```
def add(a,b):
    """ docstrings"""
    a = a + 2
    b = b + 2
    c = a +b
    return c
```

Example A2:

```
def add(a,b):
    """ docstrings"""
    a = a + 2
    b = b + 2
    c = a +b

    return c
```

Example B1:

```
def add(a,b):
    """ docstrings"""
    if a > b:
       c = a + b
    else:
       c = a -b
    return c
```

Example B2:

```
def add(a,b):
    """ docstrings"""
    if a > b:
       c = a + b
    else:
       c = a -b

    return c
```

Example C1:

```
def add(a):
    """ docstrings"""
    for i in range(3):
       a = a + i
    return a
```

Example C2:

```
def add(a):
    """ docstrings"""
    for i in range(3):
       a = a + i

    return a
```

Which ones are the common practice in these use cases (A, B, C)? Does anything change when a block of if-else or a loop is involved before the return statement?

Comment: There's no common practice. I prefer to have blank line before return statement, others might prefer not to. Follow the convention of the project you're working on, or stick to yours if it's a new project.

Comment: From [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#blank-lines): "_Use blank lines in functions, sparingly, to indicate logical sections._". It comes down to personal preference or on the project's conventions, as Maroun said. For me is a per case decision; in small functions like yours I usually don't leave a blank line before the return statement.

Comment: Regarding blank lines after docstrings see the examples in [PEP 257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/): no blank line.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's no common practice (at least I've seen None in the style PEPs) for `return`s and blank lines.

But there is one regarding blank lines and the docstring (see [PEP 257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/)):

> There's no blank line either before or after the docstring.

But also:

> Insert a blank line after all docstrings (one-line or multi-line) **that document a class** -- generally speaking, the class's methods are separated from each other by a single blank line, and the docstring needs to be offset from the first method by a blank line.

(Emphasis mine)

I've often seen blank lines after loops, also sometimes blank lines before `return` but that depends on the length of the function/loop. It's often more important to decide on one style (if there's no existing convention) and stick to it.

As [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds) put it:

> A style guide is about consistency. Consistency with this style guide is important. Consistency within a project is more important. Consistency within one module or function is the most important.

However it's important that PEP8 recommends to use blank lines sparingly and to separate logical sections (I don't think it's a logical section to "return" but YMMV):

> Use blank lines in functions, **sparingly**, to indicate **logical sections**.

(Emphasis mine)